# collection_select content is not showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm currently trying to display the **organization** which a content identifies themselves with via a **collection_select** form.

The issue is that after creating a new contact and choosing an organization. The organization doesn't display.

I have tried searching the web for an answer so far but nothing has helped. I have also tried everything that I can think of is the issue with my code.

Here are my **models**:

```
class Contact < ApplicationRecord
has_many :contact_orgs
has_many :organizations, through: :contact_orgs
accepts_nested_attributes_for :organizations
end

class Organization < ApplicationRecord
has_many :contact_orgs
has_many :contacts, through: :contact_orgs
end

class ContactOrg < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :contact
belongs_to :organization
accepts_nested_attributes_for :organization
end
```

Here is my **schema.rb**:

```
create_table "contact_orgs", force: :cascade do |t|
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.integer "contact_id"
t.integer "organization_id"
t.index ["contact_id"], name: "index_contact_orgs_on_contact_id"
t.index ["organization_id"], name: "index_contact_orgs_on_organization_id"
end

create_table "contacts", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string "first_name"
t.string "last_name"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "organizations", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string "name"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.string "industry"
end
```

Here is my **contact_controller.rb**:

```
private
def contact_params
params.require(:contact).permit(:first_name, :last_name, 
organizations_attributes: [:name, :industry])
end

def new
@contact = Contact.new
end

def show
@contact = Contact.find(params[:id])
end

def create
@contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
if @contact.save
redirect_to @contact
else
render 'new'
end
end
```

Here is my **contact/new.html.erb**:

```
<%= form_with scope: :contact, url: contact_path, local: true do |form| %>

<p>
<%= form.label :first_name %><br>
<%= form.text_field :first_name %>
</p>

<p>
<%= form.label :last_name %><br>
<%= form.text_field :last_name %>
</p>

<p>
<%= form.label :organization_id, "Organization:" %><br>
<%= form.collection_select :organization_id, Organization.order(:name), :id, :name, {}, {multiple: true} %>
</p>

<p>
<%= form.submit %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

Here is my **contact/show.html.erb**:

```
<p>
<strong>First name:</strong>
<%= @contact.first_name %>
</p>

<p>
<strong>Last Name:</strong>
<%= @contact.last_name %>
</p>
<hr>

<p>
<strong>Organizations:</strong>
<ul>
<% @contact.organizations.each do |organization| %>
<li><%= organization.name %></li>
<% end %>

</ul>
</p>
```

Here is what my **Rails Server** is saying when I refresh my **localhost:3000/contact/2** page.

[image: Here is what my Rails Server is saying when I refresh my localhost:3000/contact/2 page.]

Here is what is in my Rails Console:

```
2.4.1 :001 > Contact.find(2).organizations
Contact Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "contacts".* FROM "contacts" WHERE "contacts"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Organization Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "organizations".* FROM "organizations" INNER JOIN "contact_orgs" ON "organizations"."id" = "contact_orgs"."organization_id" WHERE "contact_orgs"."contact_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["contact_id", 2], ["LIMIT", 11]]=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

Here is my **routes.rb** file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
get 'welcome/index'

resources :contacts, :organizations

root 'welcome#index'
end
```

Thank you ahead of time :)

**Edit**: 
Added **Contacts#Show** method and **Contact.find(2).organization** via Rails c command.

Added **routes.rb**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you’re using a joins table (`ContactOrg`) you really are trying to create a new `ContactOrg` record when you create a `Contact`, not assign it to `Organization`, which is how your code reads.

**EDIT**

While my first statement above still has a (little) bit of merit (you are in fact creating a joins record), you can definitely let rails help you out and you were pretty close in your original answer. Here's code only where there are updates, I tried to highlight changes.

**app/models/contact.rb**

```
class Contact < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :contact_orgs
  has_many :organizations, through: :contact_orgs

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :organizations # you were correct here
end
```

**app/views/contact/new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_with model: :contact, local: true do |form| %>
  # use :model here so you can ultimately use this form for both new and edit.
  # The model method will infer the correct path

  ... contact fields here as you have them ...

  <p>
    <%= form.collection_select :organization_ids, Organization.order(:name), :id, :name, {}, {multiple: true} %>
    # the attribute for organization_id should be plural because you're accepting multiple
  <p>

  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

**app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb**

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController


  ... new, show, and create as you have them ...

   private # private methods should go after all public methods 

   def contact_params
     params.require(:contact).permit(:first_name, :last_name, organization_ids: [])
     # again, the attribute you're passing in is called organization_ids, and you give it an empty array
   end
end
```

Comment: I made the appropriate changes like you showed but still, the organization for a contact isn't showing in my show view. I'm wondering if it's something within the **views/contact/show.html.erb** file (which is above).

Comment: I just noticed your url at the top of your form was set to the `contacts_index_path`. This makes me think your form is not actually hitting your create action (because it's hitting the index action). I updated my answer with what should be the path for the create action (you can do `rake routes` to confirm, it should be something like `POST contacts#create`

Comment: Okay I think that you're on to it because once I tried to create a new contact I was given a `ActionController::UrlGenerationError` which reads `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"contact"}, missing required keys: [:id]`. I'm not sure what this is exactly saying nor how to go about fixing it.

Comment: great! going back to `rake routes`, there should be a route like `GET contacts/:id contacts#show`. The `:id` part would refer to the id of the `contact` at this point that you are passing through (`@contact`). It would appear when you're hitting the show page, you are either not passing in @contact, or your @contact isn't actually a saved object, so the `id` is nil.

Comment: Can you find your newly created contact in the console? Also, I didn't mean to drop your `show` action in my answer, I hope that is still actually in your code.

Comment: Yes, the `show` action is still in my code. Okay so I put in `Contact.find(:all)` into the rails console and this is what I received back.

Comment: `  Contact Load (10.5ms)  SELECT  "contacts".* FROM "contacts" WHERE "contacts"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]
` `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Contact with 'id'=all` --- so it seems as if my @contact isn't actually a saving objects (which confuses me because it's displaying a contacts `:first_name` and `:last_name` to my views).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161372/discussion-between-inveterateliterate-and-miklki14567).

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

1. You are not able to save the organizations to your contract.
   You can check in your `rails c` by Contact.find(2).organizations.
2. We never use to write new and create in the private method.

Your private method should not contain any of the curd.

In your **app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb**

```
private

def contact_params
  params.require(:contact).permit(
    :first_name, 
    :last_name, 
    organizations_attributes: [
      :name, 
      :industry
    ]
 )
end
```

In your **app/views/contact/new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_with scope: :contact, url: contact_index_path, local: true do |form| %>

  <p>
    <%= form.label :first_name %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :first_name %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= form.label :last_name %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :last_name %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= form.fields_for :organizations do |o| %>
      <%= o.label :organization %><br>
      <%= o.collection_select(:organization_id, Organization.all,
                          :id, :org_name,
                          {:prompt => 'Please select the organization'}) %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Okay I tried this and it seems to have saved the **organization_id** but it's still not displaying to my **views/contact/show.html.erb** file.

Comment: what have you got Contract.find(2).organizations .

Comment: Shoot alright so I checked Contact(2).organizations again and it seems to not have saved like I once thought. Alright, I updated my code. Check out my controller section and Console section.

Comment: put your private method in the bottom of the controller and create a new contract and then go to the show page for that contract .it will work

Comment: No I understand that and but the organization isn't showing

Answer (score 0):

Your contract_controller do not initialize **@contact** used in *show.html.erb* because there isn't any show method does it that.

Try to add in contact_controller

```
def show
  @contact = Contact.find(param[:id])
end
```

PS: when you call show method be sure to pass to it a contact.id

I hope this help you.

Comment: Oh no. I have a show method. The @contact is working within my show view. The part that isn't working is the part which starts with `<% @contact.organizations.each do |organization| %>`.